# Not able to send images from frontend to the backend

Tags: node.js, express, next.js

**Im trying to send my a group of images from my input to the backend but im not able to get those images in the backend getting them as undefined or [] so can someone tell me how to fix this issue ?
Im using nextjs 14
The images are defined i can see them on the console !!**

```
'use client';
const Page = () => {
    console.log("Component rendered");
    const [isUploading, setIsUploading] = useState(false);
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
    const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('');
    const router = useRouter();
    const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
    const [iamgeb, setIamgeb] = useState(null);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('title', title);
    formData.append('description', description);
    formData.append('price', price);
    formData.append('file', []);
    async function handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //console.log(formData.get('iamgeb'));
        try {
            console.log(formData);
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/addProduct', formData, {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                },
            });
          
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            
        };
        setTitle('');
        setDescription('');
        setPrice('');
        setImage(null);
        setIamgeb(null);
        /*setTimeout(() => {
            router.push('/products');
        }, 3000);*/
    }
    const convertToBase64 = (file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
            reader.onerror = (error) => reject(error);
        });
    };
    const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target?.files;
        if (!file || file.length === 0) {
            console.log("File not found");
        } else {
            formData.delete('file[]');
            for (let i = 0; i < file.length; i++) {
                formData.append('file[]',file[i]);
            }
        }
    };
   
export default Page;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, looks like you set up the formData "file" field, but never added the output of the Base64 conversion... the request is sending the empty array without the state value (And I'm not seeing any console.log message saying this field is setup right by the "handleImageChange").

```
formData.append('file', []); //this can be clearing the "file" field you setup at "handleImageChange"
```

Also, is not common to convert images to Base64 to store them (the output is not smaller than the .jpg file, you are not saving space here); instead, you could save the files as images on your server. For that, I've always used [Multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer).

PS: if you stick with the Base64 aproach, keep in mind this conversion, and the setState operation, are async; be careful not to see an image on the console.log after the request is sent!